# No WhatsApp option in sharing in photos

Tags: 8.1, whatsapp, photos

When I want to share an image/photo from Photos, I can't see WhatsApp in the list of apps.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- Open the Photos app
- Select a specific image/photo
- Select the "share" option
- This is where I can't see WhatsApp

I am using Windows Phone 8.1 and wanted to share an image/photo from the screenshots folder.

Comment: Which version of WhatsApp do you have installed?

Comment: WhatsApp does not support share from pictures in the Screenshot folder. Is it the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is a slight problem with sharing the Screenshots directly through the "Share" option in Photos app.You can not share them directly.For other types photos you can,but not for the Screenshots.Now if you still want to share them,You are given only one choice.

- open the whatsapp and then send that photo from within the whatapp app.

Comment: wow, never noticed that - but you're right!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to update your phone to the latest OS and firmware version. I am using Windows Phone 8.1 with the Denim update and in my share options I can see WhatsApp and other shareable applications.